# selectOneMenu does not change the value of the bean object

Tags: jsf, javabeans, onchange, managed-bean, selectonemenu

So I have the following code:

```
<h:inputText value = "#{listAllBookings.searchText}">
  <f:ajax listener="#{listAllBookings.printValues()}" event="keyup" render="myTable"/>
</h:inputText>             
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{listAllBookings.selectedAttr}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="GUEST" itemValue="GUEST"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="HOTEL" itemValue="HOTEL"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And my printValues method:

```
public void printValues() {
    System.out.println("searchText:"  + searchText + " and selectedAttr: " + selectedAttr);
}
```

So as you can see the code above is pretty simple.
The problem is that I can't change the value of the selectedAttr value. I already checked if I have the appropriate getter and setter methods.
The value of the selectedAttr remains null, while the searchText value changes.

The current output looks like this:

[image: output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify a component for execution with your `ajax` requests. So only the textfield is executed.

Add an `id` to the `selectOneMenu` and execute it:

```
<h:inputText value="#{listAllBookings.searchText}">
  <f:ajax listener="#{listAllBookings.printValues()}" event="keyup" render="myTable"
  execute="@this selectSomething"/>
</h:inputText>             
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectSomething" value="#{listAllBookings.selectedAttr}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="GUEST" itemValue="GUEST"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="HOTEL" itemValue="HOTEL"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

But you could also execute the surrounding form via `execute="@form"`

**See also**

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{listAllBookings.selectedAttr}">
<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{listAllBookings.printValues()}" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="GUEST" itemValue="GUEST"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="HOTEL" itemValue="HOTEL"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: OP is not using PrimeFaces for all we know